# Haskell Webserver: maintaining application state

Tags: haskell, functional-programming, happstack

I'm trying to get more familiar with Haskell by developing web-app-ish services.

Say I'm developing a web-server and I want to keep persistent state between requests; a counter, for instance.  What is the Haskell way of doing things?

I came across this [discussion](http://bb10.com/haskell-cafe/2007-02/msg00589.html) on my Google search.  The proposed solution looks like a good example of what not to do.

One idea I had was having the request handler take in an MVar:

```
requestHandler :: MVar State -> IO (Maybe Response)
```

When registering the handler, it could be curried with an MVar created in main.

There must be a better way.  I can't help but think I'm approaching this problem in a non-functional way.

Thanks!

Comment: Why try to carry persistent state on the server itself? Seems to me Haskell would match much better with a RESTful design.

Comment: What's "non-functional" about that approach? You have some state you need to share, so you wrap it up and pass around the reference. Seems pretty straightforward to me.

Comment: sclv: I'm wondering if there was more of a FRP approach.

Comment: You say that you want a functional solution, but I suspect that you actually want a [compositional solution](http://www.haskellforall.com/2012/08/the-category-design-pattern.html).

Comment: Don't know if it is helpful but this is a example how I do it, https://github.com/gertcuykens/haskell-design let me know if it needs explanation

Answer (score 4):

You probably want [acid-state](http://www.happstack.com/docs/crashcourse/AcidState.html#acid_state), which gives you that exactly: persistent state for Haskell data types.  The documentation I linked even starts out with a request counter, just like you asked for.

Note that MVars are not persistent; the counter would get reset when the server is restarted.  If that's actually the behavior you want I suggest you use a [TVar](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/stm) instead; that way you can update the counter atomically without locks or the risk of deadlocks that go with them.

Answer (score 1):

If you like persistence and TVars, you can use [DBRefs](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/TCache), that have the same semantics and the same usage patterns as TVars. You must define a unique key for the state and you have automatic file persistence. For database persistence it is necessary to define an IResource instance.

The state will have a unique counter for each session:

```
import Data.Map as M
import Data.TCache
import Data.TCache.DefaultPersistence

type Counter= Int
type SessionId :: String
data State= State SessionId Counter deriving (Read, Show, Typeable)

instance Indexable State where
        key (State k _)= k 

requestHandler :: Request -> DBRef State -> IO (Maybe Response)
```